# Advanced Custom Fields - Disable Users to Edit Custom Fields

Tags: plugins, permissions, advanced-custom-fields

I don't really know how to explain this, so this will most probably not make much sense.

Basically, I made a custom field (drop-down selection) for the Add/Edit User page, and I want to be the only one who can edit this. Like... when users go to the Edit User page, they can change the value of this field, which I don't want them to be able to do. I would at least like this field to be invisible to them, but not completely disappear, as I still do need this field.

Answer (score 3):

If you are the only "Administrator" and the rest of the users is lower level roles it is possible to achieve this. ACF has the option to set a rule to only display it based on user role.

Under "Edit Field Group" (where you setup the fields) there is a tab called "Location" where this is set (see the attached screenshot).

[image: ACF rules - Only display for administrators]

Comment: I know about this. Ah, it's really hard to explain what I mean. Like... I want it to be there for every single user, but I don't want them to be able to edit it.

Comment: You're not talking about `read-only`, are you? If so, you either set the attribute in ACF (**if you can**, that is), or you could add the attribute by means of jQuery.

Comment: I guess so. Or it can be hidden from them, but no from me (on their profile). As long as they aren't able to touch it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could just check the `current_user_id` and depending on that set the field to `hidden` with the default value, or to the select with all the values you want to provide (to you).

**// Edit**

Short example:

```
<?php if (YOUR_ID === get_current_user_id()) : ?>
    <select id="UNIQUE_FIELD_NAME" name="UNIQUE_FIELD_NAME" value="whatever">
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
    </select>
<?php else : ?>
    <input type="hidden" id="UNIQUE_FIELD_NAME" name="UNIQUE_FIELD_NAME" value="whatever" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Problem with this is that the Advanced Custom Fields plugin doesn't really give you the option to edit the output of the fields directly like this.

Comment: @jzatt Yes, I was assuming this, after I read your answer. You wouldn't go that way of restricting the _per user_  question to a _per role_  answer if there were any other way, right? If so, please just live your life as if there were no answer from me. :)

Comment: Um, I don't understand. Where do I put this, exactly? Sorry, I'm a complete noob at this.